# Divert http to https with WordPress on IIS

Tags: ssl, https, iis, http

I have a WordPress site **running on IIS**. The site has an associated SSL Certificate. Right now I am able to access the site with http and https.

How can I get my http to redirect to https?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to update all of the URLs in your database to the HTTPS protocol:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://example.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. In the "*search for…*" and "*replace with…*" fields:

   - **Replace**: `http://example.com` (non-HTTP)
   - **With**: `https://example.com` (HTTPS)

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Additionally, you can also look into using the [Remove HTTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-http/) plugin which automatically scans your website and removes both HTTP and HTTPS protocols from your URL links. This will resolve [mixed content warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).